# Period doubling bifurcation in a quadratic map

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, bifurcation

I am attempting the find $\mu$ for which the map
$$x_{n+1} = \mu + x_n^2$$
undergoes a period doubling bifurcation.

I understand that finding the fixed points of the map is the first step towards finding the period doubling, and I find these to be
$$x_{*} = \frac{1}{2} (1 \pm \sqrt{1-4\mu})$$
in terms of the parameter. What I don't understand is where to go from here. Do I need to find the fixed point of the second iterate of the map? Or do I need to ensure that the condition that $f_{\mu}'(x_{*}) = -1$ is satisfied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your iterated map is given by:

$$f_{\mu}(x)=x^2+\mu$$

Your fixed points are correctly given as:

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4\mu})$$

If a period change occurs at the fixed point $x_1$, then necessarily

$$|f'(x_1)|\ge 1$$

so it suffices to solve the equation:

$$|f'(x_1)|= 1\Rightarrow$$
$$|2x|_{x=x_1}=1\Rightarrow$$
$$|1+\sqrt{1-4\mu}|=1\Rightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{1-4\mu}=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\mu=\frac{1}{4}$$

And now you can be sure that the iterated map $f_{1/4}(x)$, will suffer some sort of period change at $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$.

Work similarly for the other fixed point.

---

For later verification, note that this map is the Mandelbrot map for the Julia Set with $\mu=c=1/4$, so the bifurcation point is the right cusp of the set for this $c$.

Comment: Does it suffice here to check only that the eigenvalue is on the unit circle? I was under the impression that if $f_{\mu}'(x_{1,2}) = 1$ then you are in the situation where you obtain a pitchfork bifurcation. Does this distinction matter?

Comment: @jamesFielder: Before a map changes from attracting to repelling (and vice-versa) it has to become neutral at some FIXED point $x_0$ and that's exactly what $|f'_{\mu}(x_0)|=1$ means. It is a pitchfork of period 2, with the pitchfork starting at $z=1/2$ (the neutral point). But the pitchfork's coordinates, all EXCEPT $z=1/2$ are complex conjugates, so you see it only as a boundary curve on the complex plane of the corresponding Julia set for $c=1/4$.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. Thanks very much for clarifying that for me.